# Can a VIEW in MySQL read from one table and store into another?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Does MySQL have anything like `aufs`? I want to use my production tables read-only and store changes into another table or database if possible.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

> Does MySQL have anything like aufs?

No

**Option1 - Use replication**

You can put the (read-only) production database on one server and the change database on another server (can be on the same machine).
If you set the change database as a slave of the production database, all changes that happen (from some other source perhaps) will be replicated to your change database.
Changes in the change database will not be passed on to the production database.

The fact that the change database is not in sync with the production database may cause problems with the (one way) synchronization but you'd have to experiment with that.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html

**Option 2 - dirty hack with triggers**

You can put a trigger on your production table and have the trigger diverge the data to somewhere else.
**warning**  this is a filthy hack and not recommend use of triggers at all.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER bu_prod_table1_each BEFORE UPDATE ON prod_table1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE change_table1 c SET c.field1 = NEW.field1, c.field2 = NEW.field2 
    WHERE c.id = OLD.id;
  IF NEW.id <> OLD.id THEN
    UPDATE change_table1 SET c.id = NEW.id WHERE c.id = OLD.id;
  END IF;
  /*reverse the changes in the production table*/
  SET NEW.id = OLD.id;
  SET NEW.field1 = OLD.field;
  .....
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

You'd have to create these triggers for UPDATE, DELETE, and INSERT.
And you'd have to put triggers on each and every table in production.

Answer (score 0):

In other SQL implementations (e.g. SQL Server), an `INSTEAD OF` trigger on a `VIEW` can achieve the goal of reading from one table and writing to another. However, mySQL does not to my knowledge support `INSTEAD OF` triggers.